# Is it possible to use "any" in this sentence: "As for extreme sports, I wouldn't like to take up any"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is it possible to use *any* in this sentence:
*"As for extreme sports, I wouldn't like to take up any."* 
Also, is this sentence grammatically correct or should it be 
*"As for extreme sports, I wouldn't like to take any (of them) up."*

Comment: Both your versions are syntactically fine, but idiomatically the first one wouldn't work very well unless you put heavy stress on ***any*** (which is also possible, but not so *necessary* with the second version). There's also the completely "unstressed" version *...I wouldn't like to take them up* (without including ***any*** at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the phrase *"As for"* at the beginning of the sentence you have moved the indefinite article object to the beginning of the sentence.

You would use this structure presumably to tie this sentence's object to a preceding sentence where *"extreme sports"* are mentioned.

This is perfectly acceptable for this reason and this is because if you removed *"as for"* you would move the object to the end of the sentence and it would therefore read:

*"I wouldn't take up any extreme sports"*

The second sentence, *"As for extreme sports, I wouldn't like to take any (of them) up."*  while grammatically correct will sound wrong to many English speakers as it ends with "up".

While here "up" is being used as part of the compound verb *"to take up"*, *"Up"* is often used as a preposition.  While it is not wrong to end a sentence with a preposition it is discouraged and sounds particularly informal. Additionally, with three words, *"any (of them)"*, occurring in the middle of the compound verb many people will not read *"up"*  as part of the compound verb *"take up"*.

To keep this form and prevent *"up"* from potentially sounding like a preposition at the end of the sentence you could rephrase this as.

*"As for extreme sports, I wouldn't like to take up any of them."*

Comment: so, just to clarify, it is not incorrect to say "As for extreme sports, I wouldn't like to take up any." (without "of them")?

Comment: Correct is it perfectly acceptable as the "of them" is implied.